# Rust: `while true` does not compile but `loop`does

Tags: loops, rust, while-loop

I am very new to Rust and to low-level languages in general. I noticed that in the code below, if I replace `loop` with `while true` the code doesn't compile anymore. I would actually expect the version with `loop` not to compile as well, because the return statement is inside an if statement, so not all code paths would return a value.

```
pub fn two_sum(numbers: Vec<i32>, target: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut left = 0;
    let mut right = numbers.len() - 1;
    loop {
        while numbers[left] + numbers[right] > target { 
            right -= 1;
        }
        if numbers[left] + numbers[right] == target {
            break vec![left as i32 + 1, right as i32 + 1];
        } else { 
            left += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I am also open to suggestions on how to make the code above more Rust idiomatic!

Comment: Please always give the full error by `cargo check`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because `loop`'s control flow is much better understood by the compiler:

- the compiler understands that a `loop` is executed at least once
- a `loop` without a `break` has type `!` (never), which unifies with all types (in type-system lingo it's a "bottom" type), a loop with a `break` has type `()`, a loop with a valued `break` has whatever type `break`'s value has
- this means the compiler can reason about loop termination (or the lack thereof), if the loop does not contain a `break` statement it knows that the code following the loop is dead, it can never execute

None of that is the case of a `while` loop, there is no special-case for `while true`, or `while false`, they're not treated any differently than any other `while` loop: as far as the compiler is concerned they can all run for 0+ iterations

Hence:

```
let mut a;
loop {
    a = 1;
    break;
}
a
```

compiles but

```
let mut a;
while true {
    a = 1;
    break;
}
a
```

does not compile. That is also why `loop` [can have a result value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#break-and-loop-values) but `while` can not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So regardless of how many code paths there are within the loop, as long as there is a valued `break` the compiler will assume the loop will evaluate thus my function is guaranteed to return a value. But there is no guarantee we'll reach the break statement. Why aren't the code paths checked within the loop? i.e in my function why isn't the compiler asking me to add a return/break statement in `else`

Comment: @Tobby2F because if you fall into the `else` then the loop will continue running, which is perfectly legitimate. The compiler simply assumes that you will hit the `break` later (or never, resulting in an infinite loop, which is legitimate too).

Comment: @Tobby2F generally solving loop termination is the halting problem, the compiler just makes heuristic assumptions based on the loop's lexical content.

Comment: I realize my last question doesn't make sense, as there would be no loop if we were to break in all code paths ...